# Why does Windows user password authentication time change with repeated attempts to log in?

Tags: windows-7, authentication, time, passwords

I was working on backing up a machine at work today and noticed that after a couple of different attempts to get the password right, windows took much longer to check if the password I put in was the correct one, going from ~1 second to ~ 10 seconds. If anyone knows how Windows looks up the password information and has an explanation that'd be great. I'm genuinely curious if this is due to some other process that takes place or if Windows just hit some random error. For info this was on Windows 7 but I've seen it on other versions as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a security feature to discourage random password guessing.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It seems like that would be the intuitive reason but I guess I was hoping for something a little more complex.

Comment: I think that when the intuitive reason is the actual reason, that's the best possible outcome.  Why would you strive for mystery and complexity?  Whether it is a useful feature is a completely separate argument.

Answer (score 0):

This helps prevent automated guesses, because a human who forgot their password will usually guess a few (less than ten or so) passwords, so the effect isn't too much of a hassle.  On the other hand, it's extremely unlikely that a machine will crack your password in few attempts, so the time penalty makes automatically guessing passwords through the login interface impossible.